# Codeigniter order by who has max value in POINTS column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

My company table column "REV" contain all rating sum and i want to order by based on rating

```
public function all_company($limit, $offset)
{
$query = $this->db
->select(['id','name'])
->from('company')
->order_by('MAX(rev)', 'desc')
->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Company Table Structure

```
ID | Name | Rev
1   name1   65
2   name2   15
3   name3   96
```

Comment: Will work for you if get this answered in MySQL SELECT statement or you need in PHP compulsory

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY on the rating table, which may prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this table structure and query for your problem :

select * from company;

select * from company_rating;

```
SELECT company.id, company.company_name, MAX(company_rating.rating)
FROM company
RIGHT JOIN company_rating ON company_rating.company_id = company.id
GROUP BY company.id
ORDER BY MAX(company_rating.rating) DESC
```

Can you try with CI Active Query :

```
$this->db->select('company.id, company.company_name, MAX(company_rating.rating)', false);
$this->db->from('company');
$this->db->join('company_rating c', 'company_rating.company_id = company.id', 'right');
$this->db->group_by('company.id'); 
$this->db->order_by('MAX(company_rating.rating)', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

and also modify your table structure like

```
CREATE TABLE  `company` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name`varchar(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `company` (`company_name`) VALUES
('ABC'),
('XYZ');

CREATE TABLE  `company_rating` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11),
  `rating` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `company_rating` (`company_id`,`rating`) VALUES
(1,2),
(1,4),
(1,5),
(2,4),
(2,7),
(2,10);
```

and also visit this [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a80e7/3)

Output Like :

```
id  company_name    rating 

1   ABC              5 

2   XYZ              10
```

I Hope it will helps

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN. Indeed, its use here is decidedly odd.

Comment: thanks Nikunj but i want to list my company as order by max rating and your output show low rating first

Comment: @NikuNjRathod codeigniter shows this error while putting order by code syntax error, unexpected 'MAX' (T_STRING).

Comment: @NikuNjRathod its a request can i get your linkedin profile to chat instantly as my issue is not resolving bro plz

Comment: @Ashraf Please check now.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod thnks bro i think code is little bit working. but table joining is giving error, i have updated my question with my current model code and error plz help me in that and also i want to display all company it is showing ony one company who has max rating.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod Please help me with this

Comment: @Ashraf Can post your table structure?

Comment: @NikuNjRathod ok i have updated table structure on question

Comment: @Ashraf Can you change data type of field com_review table inside rev_points field as integer datatype. you can visit this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp

Comment: @NikuNjRathod i have change datatype stil same error showing. Joining table field could not found. Below is given error.                                        
--Unknown column 'com_review.rev_points' in 'field list'

Comment: @NikuNjRathod thnks for ur help i have updated my question, i have tried this way to do without joining table. But order by is not showing all company based on DESC rating